# Converting batch folder creation script into python

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, for-loop, directory

I'm making a python program that will move certain folders around into different directories. Currently I'm using old batch scripts that work great - but I'm wondering how to do these exact things in python as opposed to batch so I don't have to call the .bat files. Eventually i would like to put it all into one .py and create a .exe out of it.

### Here's the things I'm trying to convert:

This script moves a few of the files (my python outputs to the notes.txt file)

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (notes.txt) do robocopy /s /MOVE "C:\Users\koka\Documents\Python Scripts\%%a" "C:\Users\koka\Desktop\OUTPUT\%%a\Notes"
pause
```

And then this script moves the remainder of the files:

```
dir /b /ad > modmovelist.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (modmovelist.txt) do robocopy /s /MOVE
"C:\Users\koka\Documents\Python Scripts\%%a" "C:\Users\koka\Desktop\OUTPUT\%%a\Mods"
```

Finally, this script will go back through all the folders and clean it up, adding all the missing folders I want under each "%%a".

```
set homepath=C:\Users\koka\Desktop\Basics
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /ad /b "%homepath%\*"') DO (
    if not exist "%homepath%\%%G\Emails"    mkdir "%homepath%\%%G\Emails"
)
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /ad /b "%homepath%\*"') DO (
    if not exist "%homepath%\%%G\Notes" mkdir "%homepath%\%%G\Notes"
)
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /ad /b "%homepath%\*"') DO (
    if not exist "%homepath%\%%G\Mods" mkdir "%homepath%\%%G\Mods"
)
```

The program executes in the order listed above.
What trips me up is that I can't find out how to account for the "%%a" - would it be another for loop? There must be a clean solution for replicating the dir command, too.

How can I convert this all to pure python?

Answer (score 0):

try looking up 'os' methods alone with 'glob' and 'shutil'. These methods will allow you to navigate the dir system of your computer and do things with the files.  You'll have to import them to use them like this: import os, import shutil, import glob.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`shutil.move(src, dst)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to Recursively move a file or directory `src` to another location `dst`.

For example, your first script could be written as:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import shutil

# Read from notes file
notes = open("notes.txt").read().splitlines()

# Loop through notes file
for n in notes:
    shutil.move("Python Scripts/" + n, "OUTPUT/" + n + "/Notes")
```

Your second batch script appears to be similar in nature, so model it after that.

For your last batch script, you don't need to have three separate for loops for each action. Instead put all the actions into one:

```
set homepath=C:\Users\koka\Desktop\Basics
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /ad /b "%homepath%\*"') DO (
    if not exist "%homepath%\%%G\Emails"    mkdir "%homepath%\%%G\Emails"
    if not exist "%homepath%\%%G\Notes" mkdir "%homepath%\%%G\Notes"
    if not exist "%homepath%\%%G\Mods" mkdir "%homepath%\%%G\Mods"
)
```

As for python, you could do this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

homepath = "Basics"

# Just get the directories within the homepath
directories = next(os.walk(homepath))[1]

for d in directories
    if not os.path.exists(homepath + "/" + d + "/Emails")
        os.mkdir(homepath + "/" + d + "/Emails")
    if not os.path.exists(homepath + "/" + d + "/Notes")
        os.mkdir(homepath + "/" + d + "/Notes")
    if not os.path.exists(homepath + "/" + d + "/Mods")
        os.mkdir(homepath + "/" + d + "/Mods")
```